# Use R to extract sections of HTML document using <b> to indicate section header

Tags: html, r, text, extract, sections

I have a few thousand large documents saved locally, where they are all saved as HTML files. Each document is about 300 pages long, and has some sections that have titles in bold letters. My goal is to do a text search in these files, and when I find the given phrase, extract the whole section that contains this phrase. My idea was to parse the html text so that it becomes a list of paragraphs, find the location of the phrase, and then extract everything from the bold letters (title of this section) just prior to bold letters just after (title of the next section).

I tried in a number of different ways, but none of them does what I want. the following was promising:

```
  myhtmlfile = "I:/myfolder/myfile.html"
  myhtmltxt2 = htmlTreeParse(myhtmlfile, useInternal = TRUE)
```

But while I can display the object "myhtmltxt2" and it looks like html with tags (which is what I need so that I can look for `"<b>"` ), it is an external pointer. So then I am not able to the command below, because grep does not work on pointers.

```
test2<-grep("myphrase",myhtmltxt2,ignore.case = T)
```

Alternatively, I did this:

```
doc.text = unlist(xpathApply(myhtmltxt2, '//p', xmlValue))
test3<-grep("myphrase",doc.text,ignore.case = T)
```

But in this case, I lost html tags in doc.text, so I no longer have `"<b>"` which is what I was going to use to indicate section to extract. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I managed this by following:

```
singleString <- paste(readLines(myHTMLfile), collapse=" ")
data11 = strsplit(singleString,"<p><b>", fixed = TRUE)
test2<- unlist(data11)

myindex<-regexpr("Myphrase </b>", test2)
```